# MySQL Multiple joins and max date

Tags: mysql, sql

I seem to be struggling with this one and I was hoping someone cold shed some light for me.

petevents will have multiple duplicate events, except the dates will be different. I only want the most current one of each petevent.

```sql
SELECT name,
       pets.id petid,
       petroutineschedules.id,
       petroutineschedules.eventid,
       timeunit,
       dateunit,
       petevents.startdate
FROM   pets
       LEFT OUTER JOIN petroutineschedules
         ON pets.id = petroutineschedules.petid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN petevents
         ON pets.id = petevents.petid
            AND petevents.eventid = petroutineschedules.eventid
WHERE  ( pets.id = 1025 )
       AND ( pets.deletedat IS NULL )
GROUP  BY petevents.startdate,
          name,
          pets.id,
          petroutineschedules.id,
          petroutineschedules.eventid,
          timeunit,
          dateunit
```

UPDATED Query from @aleroot

```
SELECT name, pets.id petid,  petroutineschedules.id prsid, petroutineschedules.eventid,    timeunit,  dateunit,  petevents.startdate,  petevents.id peid
FROM
pets

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    petroutineschedules ON pets.id = petroutineschedules.petid

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM petevents p1 
    WHERE p1.startdate = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM petevents p2 
            WHERE p1.petid = p2.petid
        ) 
) AS petevents
    ON pets.id = petevents.petid 
        AND petevents.eventid = petroutineschedules.eventid    

WHERE (pets.id = 1025) AND (pets.deletedat IS NULL)
GROUP BY petevents.startdate , name , pets.id , petroutineschedules.id ,petroutineschedules.eventid , timeunit , dateunit
ORDER BY eventid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view and left join other tables with it.

```
CREATE VIEW  PETEVNT_VW AS SELECT PETID,EVENTID, MAX(STARTDATE) AS MAXSTARTDATE GROUP BY PETID,EVENTID
```

Comment: this works pretty good. you forgot the FROM, but no big deal. thx!

Answer (score 2):

If you can have duplicate events you have to get the most new one, try in this way :

```
SELECT 
name,
pets.id petid,
petroutineschedules.id,
petroutineschedules.eventid,
timeunit,
dateunit,
petevents.startdate
FROM
pets
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
petroutineschedules ON pets.id = petroutineschedules.petid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM petevents p1 WHERE p1.startdate = 
(SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM petevents p2 WHERE p1.petid = p2.petid) ) ON pets.id = petevents.petid and petevents.eventid = petroutineschedules.eventid
WHERE
(pets.id = 1025) AND (pets.deletedat IS NULL)
GROUP BY petevents.startdate , name , pets.id , petroutineschedules.id , petroutineschedules.eventid , timeunit , dateunit
```

Basically the modified part is this one :

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM petevents p1 WHERE p1.startdate = 
    (SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM petevents p2 WHERE p1..petid = p2.petid) ) ON pets.id = petevents.petid and petevents.eventid = petroutineschedules.eventid
```

I joined with a subquery that gets latest events ...

Comment: I used your query, but I am getting NULL back from petevent.startdate and petevent.id but the row does exist.
Updated query in post

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
name,
pets.id petid,
petroutineschedules.id,
petroutineschedules.eventid,
timeunit,
dateunit,
petevents.startdate
from (
SELECT 
name,
pets.id petid,
petroutineschedules.id,
petroutineschedules.eventid,
timeunit,
dateunit,
petevents.startdate,
Rank() over (Partition BY petevents.startdate order by petevents.startdate DESC) as Rank
FROM
pets
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
petroutineschedules ON pets.id = petroutineschedules.petid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
petevents ON pets.id = petevents.petid and petevents.eventid = petroutineschedules.eventid
WHERE
(pets.id = 1025) AND (pets.deletedat IS NULL)
GROUP BY petevents.startdate , name , pets.id , petroutineschedules.id , petroutineschedules.eventid , timeunit , dateunit
)
where rank = 1
```

Comment: I am not using MS SQL. AFAIK there is no Rank() and over.